# Why does Mobx claim I am trying to change an observable value?

Tags: mobx

Every time I try to access the computed value of a mobx class instance, I get

```
[MobX] Since strict-mode is enabled, changing (observed) observable values without using an action is not allowed. Tried to modify: VoiceSettings@3.voices
```

I created a class like so:

```js
import {action, computed, makeObservable, observable} from "mobx"

export default class VoiceSettings {
    @observable language: Language = 'en';
    @observable speaker?: Voice;
    @observable voices: Voice[] = [];

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this);
        this.getAvailableVoices();
    }

    async getAvailableVoices() {
        this.voices = await Speech.getAvailableVoicesAsync();
        return this.voices;
    }

    @computed
    get speakers(): string[] {
        return this.voices
            .filter(voice => voice.language.startsWith(this.language))
            .map(voice => voice.name)
    }

    @action
    setLanguage(language: Language) {
        this.language = language;
    }
}

export const voiceSettings = new VoiceSettings();
```

This seems to only happen when i call `voiceSettings.speakers`.

**Update**
My mistake. Was tripped by the error message. I was calling the method `voice. getAvailableVoices()` somewhere else in my code

Comment: `speakers` has only a `getter`, so it is *read-only*.

Comment: Understood @connexo but surely I can do `voiceSettings.speakers.map()` on a ready-only var, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that only synchronous changes to observable data works in actions, so when `Speech.getAvailableVoicesAsync()` has resolved and is assigned to `this.voices` it's technically not inside an action anymore.

How to create asynchronous actions is [discussed in the documentation](https://mobx.js.org/actions.html#asynchronous-actions). One way of going about it is to use `runInAction`:

```js
async getAvailableVoices() {
    const voices = await Speech.getAvailableVoicesAsync();

    runInAction(() => {
        this.voices = voices;
    });

    return this.voices;
}
```